# Is there a known issue with jQuery 1.7.1 and fancybox 1.3.4?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and Fancybox 1.3.4.

Fancybox works well in other places on our site where we use jQuery 1.4.3.

I am really confident that I have the code right to launch Fancybox, but when I click on a Fancybox link, I this error:

```
t is undefined
```

I've scoured the web and it looks like other people have had this issue but there isn't a clear answer.

Is there any known issue with using these versions of jQuery and Fancybox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, fancybox v1.3.4 works perfectly fine with the [latest version of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) (v1.7.1 so far).

I have many examples of such scenario. [Check one here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/jQueryON_13dec11.html).

Check that you are not loading both versions v1.4.3. and v1.7.1, you only need one (some plugins include a jQuery version in their download). Also check that you load jQuery before any plugin that has dependency of it.

If you still have the issue, you might share your code or preferably a link so we can help you better.

Comment: I got error 'The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.' with 1.3.4 & 1.7.1. But with jQuery version 1.5.1 everything is ok. But my other plugins need more fresh version of jQuery..... uhm trying to find out smth

Comment: @Extazystas : hard to know without seeing at your code or site. Got a link?

Comment: @JFK, I solved it by including 2 versions of jQuery on 1 page with jQuery.noconflict

Comment: @Extazystas : normally, you would only need a single version of jQuery for most of your jQuery plugins, however if using fancybox v1.3.4 (and can be the case with other plugins) you need to beware that it doesn't work with jQuery v1.9+ check this for further reference http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987