# Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0 [ f.browser is undefined / Cannot read property 'msie' ]

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Fancybox breaks with the new jQuery v1.9.0.

**It affects both, Fancybox v1.3.4 and below - and - v2.1.3 and below.**

The errors shown are :

v1.3.4 :

```
Timestamp: 15/01/2013 10:03:28 AM
Error: TypeError: b.browser is undefined
Source File: ...fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
Line: 18
```

... other errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
```

In v2.1.3 :

```
Timestamp: 15/01/2013 10:09:58 AM
Error: TypeError: $.browser is undefined
Source File: h.../fancybox2.1.3/jquery.fancybox.js
Line: 139
```

If you are using this to call jQuery :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

... **any of your existing fancybox implementations will fail!!**

Comment: And that's why you should _never, ever_ use `jquery-latest.js` in production!

Comment: use latest version of fancybox 2.1.5 http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 204, accepted):

It seems like it exists a bug in jQuery reported here : **http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13183** that breaks the Fancybox script.

Also check **https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/485** for further reference.

As a workaround, rollback to **[jQuery v1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js)** while either the jQuery bug is fixed or Fancybox is patched.

---

**UPDATE** (Jan 16, 2013): Fancybox **[v2.1.4](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license)** has been released and now it works fine with jQuery v1.9.0.

<strike>For fancybox v1.3.4- you still need to rollback to **[jQuery v1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js)** or apply the **[migration script](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js)** as pointed out by @Manu's answer.</strike>

---

**UPDATE** (Jan 17, 2013): Workaround for users of **Fancybox v1.3.4** :

Patch the **[fancybox js file](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js)** to make it work with jQuery v1.9.0 as follow :

1. Open the *jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js* file (full version, **not pack version**) with a text/html editor.
2. Find around the line 29 where it says :

   ```
   isIE6 = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
   ```

   and replace it by (**EDITED** March 19, 2013: more accurate filter):

   ```
   isIE6 = navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6]/i) && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
   ```

   **UPDATE** (March 19, 2013): Also replace `$.browser.msie` by `navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6]/i)` around line 615 (and/or replace all `$.browser.msie` instances, if any), thanks [joofow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073656/joofow)
   ... that's it!

Or download the already patched version **[from HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4_patch.zip)** (UPDATED March 19, 2013 ... thanks [fairylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189971/fairylee) for pointing out the extra closing bracket)

**NOTE**: this is an unofficial patch and is unsupported by Fancybox's author, however it works as is. You may use it at your own risk ;)

Optionally, you may rather rollback to **[jQuery v1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js)** or apply the **[migration script](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js)** as pointed out by @Manu's answer.

Comment: I had the same issue crop up after pulling from the Google Ajax Libraries API CDN at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js. This pulls the latest jQuery release of 1.9.0 and the problem crops up. We pulled down the v1.8.3 release and pointed to it on the local web server and everything is fixed now. Obviously, we'd like to use the CDN but not at the expense of breaking our sliders and hover menus.

Comment: Why is the regex written `/msie [6]/i`? -- The character class `[6]` is exactly equivalent to *the character* `6`, i.e. without the brackets. That doesn't inspire very much confidence in the code… :/

Comment: @ZrajmCAkfohg : I guess because I normally validate IE versions from 6 to 8 `[6-8]` and in this case it just went as `[6]`, at the end is just a syntax convention. Anyways, if they are "exactly equivalent", then how does this affect the confidence in the code?!?! If the result with or without brackets was different and that makes room for confusion, then I would agree with you, otherwise I don't see your "...doesn't inspire confidence ..." comment very constructive at all. I would rather encourage you to post your own "confidence-inspiring" answer.

Comment: I applied the same solution to lightbox_me 2.3 and it works too.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem with opening the FancyBox a second time though...
See this sample page here: http://wasen.net/testjq1.10.2.html

Comment: @Anders : This answers proposes a patched version of fancybox, which fixes the problem. Your sample page actually uses the migration script as proposed by Manu in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14355740/1055987). It seems like the issue (using the migration script) only exists with `inline` content but works fine for images and/or iframes. I guess your best bet is to patch your fancybox v1.3.4 js file. Also check the good answer by [sabel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580985/1055987). Patches on that answer may be required too.

Comment: @JFK, yes, I have actually combined the patch and sabel's (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580985/1055987) answer and now it works fine for jQ 1.10 and above. I still have problems on jQ v2 thuogh...

Comment: @JFK thanks for the instructions but my fancybox still doesn't work, using the jQuery 1.11 though, wonder if there's anything else to be done.

Comment: @Djonatan : what version of fancybox?

Comment: @JFK the old one 1.3.4

Comment: I applied this fix, however, it does not solve it. I use `jquery-1.11.3`, `jquery-migrate-1.2.1` and `fancybox-1.3.4`

Comment: The proposed fix here is not fixing this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849046/jquery-fancybox-can-only-show-inline-window-once-second-attempt-fails-with-err

Comment: I tried the patched js file (downloaded [here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4_patch.zip)) but this also does not solve the issue that when fancybox shows the inline HTML for the first time, it removes the inline HTML and breaks when you repeat the fancybox open for a second time.

Comment: @basZero : those are completely different issues. For the one you describe check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM if that helps

Comment: @JFK thanks for the link but the workarond with unwrap did not help. I replaced Fancybox by [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) now, also free and works like a charm with jQuery 1.9+ (in my case 1.11).

Answer (score 30):

Hi this is due to new version of the jQuery => 1.9.0

you can check the update :
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

jQuery.Browser is deprecated.
you can keep latest version by adding a migration script : 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js

replace :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

by :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

in your page and its working.

Comment: +1 Interesting. In any case we all have to edit our systems to do either rollback version or apply the patch for legacy code.

Comment: Applying the patch (jquery-migrate) does not help to solve this issue with fancybox-1.3.4, jquery-1.11.3 and jquery-migrate-1.2.1... Are there any patching solutions to this without the need to upgrade to the non-free Fancybox2 ?

Answer (score 19):

Global events are also deprecated.

Here's a patch, which fixes the browser and event issues:

```
--- jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js.orig   2010-11-11 23:31:54.000000000 +0100
+++ jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js    2013-03-22 23:25:29.996796800 +0100
@@ -26,7 +26,9 @@

        titleHeight = 0, titleStr = '', start_pos, final_pos, busy = false, fx = $.extend($('<div/>')[0], { prop: 0 }),

-       isIE6 = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
+       isIE = !+"\v1",
+       
+       isIE6 = isIE && window.XMLHttpRequest === undefined,

        /*
         * Private methods 
@@ -322,7 +324,7 @@
            loading.hide();

            if (wrap.is(":visible") && false === currentOpts.onCleanup(currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts)) {
-               $.event.trigger('fancybox-cancel');
+               $('.fancybox-inline-tmp').trigger('fancybox-cancel');

                busy = false;
                return;
@@ -389,7 +391,7 @@
                        content.html( tmp.contents() ).fadeTo(currentOpts.changeFade, 1, _finish);
                    };

-                   $.event.trigger('fancybox-change');
+                   $('.fancybox-inline-tmp').trigger('fancybox-change');

                    content
                        .empty()
@@ -612,7 +614,7 @@
            }

            if (currentOpts.type == 'iframe') {
-               $('<iframe id="fancybox-frame" name="fancybox-frame' + new Date().getTime() + '" frameborder="0" hspace="0" ' + ($.browser.msie ? 'allowtransparency="true""' : '') + ' scrolling="' + selectedOpts.scrolling + '" src="' + currentOpts.href + '"></iframe>').appendTo(content);
+               $('<iframe id="fancybox-frame" name="fancybox-frame' + new Date().getTime() + '" frameborder="0" hspace="0" ' + (isIE ? 'allowtransparency="true""' : '') + ' scrolling="' + selectedOpts.scrolling + '" src="' + currentOpts.href + '"></iframe>').appendTo(content);
            }

            wrap.show();
@@ -912,7 +914,7 @@

        busy = true;

-       $.event.trigger('fancybox-cancel');
+       $('.fancybox-inline-tmp').trigger('fancybox-cancel');

        _abort();

@@ -957,7 +959,7 @@
            title.empty().hide();
            wrap.hide();

-           $.event.trigger('fancybox-cleanup');
+           $('.fancybox-inline-tmp, select:not(#fancybox-tmp select)').trigger('fancybox-cleanup');

            content.empty();
```

Comment: With the patching instructions from JFK's answer alone I had still issues when I tried to open an inline box a second time, always showing the error message "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." instead of the content, that was properly displayed on the first attempt. Using your (not so obvious) additional patches it finally works.

Comment: Just tried this solution with jQuery 1.10.2 and it seems to work. Although I also agree it's not obvious to understand the "patch" in this answer.

Comment: This is a great solution for anyone stuck with an old version of Fancybox who needs a new version of JQuery. Fixed some very perplexing bugs that I was running into.

Comment: If anyone has trouble applying the patch, here's the file with edits: http://pastebin.com/9R2VFVBQ

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still has to support legacy fancybox with jQuery 3.0+ here are some other changes you'll have to make:

**.unbind() deprecated**

Replace all instances of `.unbind` with `.off`

**.removeAttribute() is not a function**

Change lines 580-581 to use jQuery's `.removeAttr()` instead:

Old code:

```
580: content[0].style.removeAttribute('filter');
581: wrap[0].style.removeAttribute('filter');
```

New code:

```
580: content.removeAttr('filter');
581: wrap.removeAttr('filter');
```

This combined with the other patch mentioned above solved my compatibility issues.

Comment: How would you fix this statement?  b.showNavArrows?((b.cyclic&&1<h.length||0!==s)&&y.show(),
(b.cyclic&&1<h.length||s!=h.length-1)&&z.show()):(y.hide(),z.hide())},M=function(){a.support.opacity||(p.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter"),f.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter"))