# Error in every page for fancybox Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Tags: jquery, fancybox

All fancy box in my website was working fine till morning and then all of a sudden error is coming on every page and all fancy box are opening in a tab.
***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'***
I dont know where is the problem .Please help me I already spend half to figure out but no help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
         // Error here  **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'**
         $("a.fancybox").fancybox({

             'overlayShow': true,
             'autoSize': false,
             'autoResize': false,
             'autoDimensions': false,
             'enableEscapeButton': true,
             'showCloseButton': true,
             'width': 620,
             'height': 250,
             'type': 'iframe',
             'scrolling': 'no'
         });
     });
    </script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
```

Comment: you are using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` SO check  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that...

1. `http://<your-domain.com>/Content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2` doesn't result in an error (404 or otherwise)
2. `$` is still an alias for the jQuery object (you may be included some other library which redefines `$` later in the script)
3. The page doesn't define an alternative [base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) which will cause the included scripts to 404, even if they appear to work outside the page

Comment: 1. It doesn't results to error.It calls full js page.                    2.This is only javascript i included in full page                      Ijust tried to test my old version (which was working fine) which I kept in other folder also not working now.SO it is possible, problem instead of related to code there is something else like any settings etc.

Comment: It seems like error is because I am using latest version of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.....when i changed it worked at one place but still in other pages its not working.So is there any particular version I use for all javascript and fancy box.

Comment: Thanks aton.I used  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> and it worked for all pages .

Comment: @meagar, your answer saved my day, thank you! had a similar error and realized $ was being redefined elsewhere.