# Using Bootstrap & Fancybox in a single project

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox, javascript-namespaces

I am using Bootstrap and Fancybox within a single project, including it like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

The files exist and got included by Chrome.

When creating a Fancybox element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    [...]

    jQuery("a.fancy").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none'    
    });
});
```

JS throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
```

(bootstrap functions are working)

Is this a namespace problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0)

Comment: you are using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` so check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 2):

Is DOM loaded before fancybox got called? If not try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.fancy').fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this by bundle update.

looks like the most recent version of jQuery no longer supports ($.browser). The jQuery docs recommend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

I used [this](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/) and it worked well.

[jQuery 1.9 docs](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)