# console errors for 'device-width' and 'fancybox'

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am getting some console errors on my website which is preventing fancybox and quicksand from working. Since yesterday (when it was working fine), all I did was update a contact form plugin. I have tried deactivating the plugin but still no dice. Below are the errors. Can someone help me solve these?

`Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. /:10`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined includes-min.js:1`

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' includes-min.js:1`

`FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem all.js:52`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! ccc.js:215`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ ccc.js:215`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! ccc.js:215`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ ccc.js:215`

Comment: Try downgrading your jquery version to 1.8 !

Comment: It worked! Why doesn't it work with 1.9? Does this mean I have to keep 1.8.3 forever?

Comment: upgrade fancybox to v2.1.4 check  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 for more info

Comment: @Rajiv007 please answer so I can give you a check. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading your jquery version to 1.8.

This is probably due to the plugins you are using might still depends on lower version of jquery to work. So you have to keep an eye when they upgrade and then you can use 1.9.