# Fancybox not working with jQuery 2 as the former uses $.browser.msie

Tags: jquery, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fancybox doesn’t work with jQuery v1.9.0 [ f.browser is undefined / Cannot read property ‘msie’ ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)

I'm trying to switch over to jQuery 2 beta for a new static website.
I'm also using [fancybox2](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/) but the problem is that it uses `$.browser.msie` at many places.
Is there an alternative to detect the browser ?

Comment: don't.  that's why `$.browser` is gone.  detect features instead.

Comment: I can see that this has been removed in facybox version 2.1.4.

Comment: and replaced it with IE =  navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/)

Comment: Check your options http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344290/1055987