# Fancybox issue: image opens in new window

Tags: jquery, fancybox, dreamweaver

I know my way around Dreamweaver, but I still stumble when it comes to Jquery.

I've been trying to implement Fancybox on my website, so that when I click an image, an enlarged version opens on the same page.

My issue is that when I click the smaller image, the bigger one appears in a new window.
I've already looked at similar questions here on the site and used Firequery and while they gave me some idea of the problem, I seem to be unable to fix it. 
The main issue seems to be around line 12.

**Head**

```
<link href="boxtext.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Loading the css files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_scripts/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<!-- loading the script files -->
<script type="text/javacript" language="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javacript" language="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery.fancybox.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<div id="info">
<a class="fancybox" href="bigwhite.png"><img src="smallwhite.png" ></a>
</div>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of fancybox? previous versions won't work in jQuery 1.9 due to $.browser

Comment: Is jquery or fancybox working on anything else on the page? Sounds like it has no effect on your image.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344290/1055987

Comment: Kevin B - it should be the latest. Got it right off their website a couple of days ago.

Fricke - No, it should only work on the images.

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.9.0 and also the newest Fancybox, version 2, so there shouldn't be a bug