# Fancybox Slideshow works only once

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

My Fancybox slideshow only works once and stops. From what I can tell is that it's not looping back because something broke which I can't figure out what. If you go to their page to "Extended functionality" and try it out you'll see that it's not working there either.. or at least for me.

```
<!-- Add Fancybox library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/+Fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.Website.com/+Fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

<!-- Fancybox Properties -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.noConflict();

        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        padding     :  0,
        prevEffect  : 'fade',
        nextEffect  : 'fade',
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        autoPlay    : 'true',
        mouseWheel  : 'true',
        helpers     : {
            buttons : {},
            title   : {
                    type: 'outside'
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Responsive Fancybox: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Google Chrome: v24.0.1312.57

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean. If I try the examples the seem to work perfectly fine. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: If you go down to "Extended functionality" and open up a image. There's a bar that shows up at the top with various buttons. If you try to start the slideshow with the play button it will go one image forward and stop.

Comment: O.K thnx for the clarification. I can confirm this problem, but this looks like a bug in fancybox to me, so maybe file / search in the github issues: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues

Comment: If there's a bug in the plugin, you're posting in the wrong place.  SO is for help fixing _your_ code, not a bug reporting or discussion site.  Contact the developer and/or post this on Github.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah their page told me to come here or Github so I'll give a shot at Github and see how that goes. If any one figures it out please give me a heads up. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that there is a bug if using jQuery 1.9.x

Fancybox v2.1.3 was broken using jQuery 1.9.x as you can [see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987). Then v2.1.4 was released to make it work with jQuery v1.9.x but it seems to me that the `buttons` helpers js file has to be patched as well.

As a workaround, you can rollback to jQuery v1.8.3.

See a **[working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bpgP3/)** using jQuery 1.8.3.

See a **[broken JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PpdXT/)** using jQuery 1.9.1.

PS. I did open an issue at **[github](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/532)**

** **UPDATE :**

The issue was fixed in the **[last commit](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/commit/6208e1213bec87cdb6b13b134a3fd3d425802c24)** (not updated in fancyapps home page samples neither the downloadable file though)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this causes your problem, but if you set `jQuery.noConflict();` you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` like this: `jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({...`