# fancybox 2.1.4 autoPlay option did not work properly

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, autoplay

I downloaded the fancybox source code sample from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license.
Please look at the following short of script:

`

#### Thumbnail helper

```
    <a class="fancybox_thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox_thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="2_b.jpg"><img src="2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox_thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="3_b.jpg"><img src="3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

`
And below is the script

`$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({ autoPlay: true});`
`$.fancybox.open($(".fancybox_thumbs").get(), fancyboxOptions);`

When page loaded, the fancybox would opened the overlay, the slideshow automatically switched from the first image to the second one, then it did not work anymore.

I did some research and google. I saw the site http://jsfiddle.net/GjNnj/3/ worked well.
I checked it and I couldn't see anything wrong, same script, same version fancybox.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: This was already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/q/15007825/1055987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using jQuery v1.9+ and there is an issue with the `buttons helper` and jQuery v1.9+ that was already reported **[HERE](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/532)** ... and it hasn't been resolved yet.

The JSFIDDLE you mention in your question is using *jQuery v1.8.3* so this is why is working.

Your workaround, while the bug is fixed, is to rollback to jQuery v1.8.3.

PS. Is actually the `buttons helper` js file that manages the slide show's *play/autoplay* option, not the `thumbnail helper` ;)