# Link a text to a dialog box containing an iframe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

Say I have this text `Click me`, and I want a modal window, which contains an iframe to a website (eg., `www.google.com`) to come up whenever one clicks on the text.

How should I go about doing this? I did some googling and an example of the iframe

```
%iframe{:src => "http://www.google.com"}
```

But I am not sure how I could use it ...

Here's the structure of my view file (`html.haml`), I tried something like this (but it didn't work!):

```
...
%li
  = User_name
  = link_to 'Click me' %iframe{:src => "http://www.google.com"}
%li
...
```

Again, how do I open a popup when some one clicks on the 'Click me' text?

Comment: you aren't sure how to handle the js to render your iframe? and do you mean an actual dialog box or just in a pop-up or modal window?

Comment: Well, perhaps I shouldn't have been too specific about the dialog. Yes, I just want a popup window that appears inside the current window (not the kind that would open in new tab/window)

Comment: I'm also not sure what you want. Do you want an overlay to open?

Comment: @SoonDead Do you use facebook? If so, do you notice when you click on 'Click to change photo' in your profile page, you'd get a popup window asking you to choose some photo to be your profile pic? ... I kind of want to do the same thing (It's just simple in my case in that I don't want a file chooser or anything, I just want a popup that contains on iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you do not want to use an iframe for displaying the content from a url, instead you want to shoe it in a pop up window. Yo can use [fancybox-rails gem](https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails). after installing the gem as described in the readme add this in your view file

```
%li
  = User_name
  = link_to 'Click me', "http://www.google.com", :class => "iframe"
```

and this in your javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.iframe").fancybox();
});
```

You can read more about the uses [here](http://fancybox.net/). There are many other jquery plugins available for the same.

Comment: Is that a dot (`.` after the `'Click me'`? Or did you mean a colon?

Comment: Is there anything else I need to add? (Because when I click on the link, i t opens a new window)

Comment: Did you install the fancybox gem?

Comment: Yes, I did install the gem (and edit my applicaion.css and application.js files)

Comment: Do you get any error in firebug console if you are using FF. or any other web developer tool.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read#14344290)

Answer (score 1):

Use a link with its `target` attribute set to the value of the `name` attribute on your modal `<iframe>`:

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="modal">Open Bing in an iframe</a>
<iframe src="#" name="modal"></iframe>
```

Then in your JS:

```
var modalTriggers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[target=modal]'));
var modal = document.querySelector('iframe[name=modal]');

modalTriggers.forEach(function(trigger){
    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.classList.toggle('active');
    }, false);
});
```

And Some CSS:

```
iframe[name=modal] {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    height: 92%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4%; left: 4%;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

iframe[name=modal].active {
    display: block;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ihogol/1/quiet) <sub>[(edit)](http://jsbin.com/ihogol/1/edit)</sub>

[On MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#name-attribute)

Comment: note that he said: "inside the current window (not the kind that would open in new tab/window)" in the comments above

Comment: @Brad This opens the website in the iframe, not a new tab/window.

Comment: P.S. I'm no big fan of Bing. Google just doesn't like being in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple ways to do this if i understand you correctly.  this is a simple approach if you include jquery into your html

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#myIframe').show(); 
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="clickMe" name="clickMe" type="button"/>
    <iframe id="myIframe" style="display:none;" src="http://www.othersite.com/some/path?param1=value1&param2=value2">
        <p>Placeholder text; only shows up if the page DOESN'T render!</p>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

you'd also want to style your iframe to behave like a modal window...there are lots of tutorials on that....  as well as handle the closing behaviors

this is a more in depth explanation http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial