# Problems loading page with jQuery in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 1.3.4 to load a page inside it (from the same domain).

Everything looks ok, but if I use jQuery also on the page loaded in fancybox, it "overrides" some functions on the parent page (for example, fancybox won't work the second time).

If I don't use it, then the jQuery depended scripts won't work on the loaded page, but I can close and reopen fancybox again.

The loaded page address is defined in href and it uses the stylesheet of the parent page.

What's causing the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: Use only one instance of jQuery, preferably the highest version up to jQuery v1.8.3. Since you are using fancybox v1.3.4, beware that version doesn't work with jQuery v1.9+. check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 for more. Also, if the opened page needs its own scripts and styles, then why you don't open it using `iframe` mode?