# how to avoid fancybox and jqgrid coflict?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, fancybox

I have **jqgrid and facybox** in my file. The problem is they both not work at a time. If jQuery's are enabled that are required for grid then fanybox doesn't work & vice-versa.
I want both of them to work at a time. how can I avoid fancybox and jqgrid conflict?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code that explains how have you implemented those?
Both HTML and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be important which exactly version of every product you use. On [the page](http://bitbonsai.com/facybox/) one can read

> Requires jQuery >= 1.2+. Important: 1.9+ will break facybox. Wait for
>   a new version.

You can use the last version of jqGrid (4.5.0) with jQuery 1.8.3, 1.7.2 or 1.6.4 for example. Even more old versions like jQuery 1.4.4 will work with the last version jqGrid.

I hope that choosing of versions of facybox and jQuery will solve your problem.

Comment: If you are using fancybox v1.3.4, it will fail with jQuery 1.9+. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 for more. If using fancybox v2.1.4, it shouldn't be any issue, just make sure you are loading only one instance of jQuery (you may not need one for jqgrid and one for fancybox)

Comment: @JFK: What I wrote is: one have to choose correct version of jQuery. Akbar Shaikh don't included **no version information** in his question. So I guess that he used wrong version of jQuery (the version which is incompatible to version fancybox which he used). For example he can try to use jQuery v1.8.3.

Comment: correct, I just meant to complement your answer ... I guess I forgot to address to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try noConflict of jQuery

```
 $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```