# Pictures show up one by one, not as an iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here's the page I'm having trouble with:

http://www.benjamine-immobilier.com/a-vendre/3-pieces-chartres-28

I don't understand why, but the pictures don't show up as a fancybox. When I change the name of the class of the pictures, then the pictures show up on full screen but one by one.

When I download and install the plugin Fancybox, then my menu doesn't work anymore (Annonces doesn't show A vendre, A louer, Vendu / Loué)

I have no idea why. What I want is simply to be able to see the pictures as a Fancybox when I click on one in the sidebar gallery.

Comment: You have 2 javascript error's... First try to get rid of them: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined jquery.address-1.5.js:343`

Comment: Upgrade fancybox plugin or downgrade your jquery version. You can have a look at jquery migrate: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your version of jQuery 1.9.1 is too 'new'. Fancybox uses $.browser built into jQuery, which Fancybox has a dependency on and was dropped in jQuery 1.9.

In Chrome Dev tools, Console is outputting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
```

I'd suggest you either revert back to older jQuery or pull out the $.browser function from the old jQuery and load it.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! How do I do that though ? :S

Comment: Inside functions.php you should be able to change the jQuery version from '1.9.1' to 1.8.1 - it's being loaded from Google CDN so this will be quite simple, have a search for it.

Comment: I did this : http://mhuntdesign.com/blog/jquery/change-default-jquery-version-wordpress replacing both 1.4.2 with 1.8.1 in my functions-twentyeleven.php file but it still doesn't work... sorry to bother but I don't really understand it perfectly

Comment: when I open the source code of the webpage, I see this line : <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.benjamine-immobilier.com/wp-content/themes/wptheme2/framework/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?ver=1.9.1'></script>

should I try and modify it?

Comment: You won't be able to modify it unless you find out where it's being called from in your /theme/ folder :) it's dynamically generated by WordPress.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for it! thanks. If you have any idea that could help me find it faster, don't hesitate :D anyway thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Would try and help but each theme folder is totally different as to the whereabouts, dependant on the theme author. If you manage to solve it then please mark as solved , thanks!