# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

Im using wordpress and i install a plugin called form-lightbox but i have a error in console of chrome:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var iFrame_1369701509296 = jQuery("#form-lightbox-1369701509296 iframe").attr("src");
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery(".fl_box-1369701509296").fancybox({
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
                "type" :"inline",
                "href" :"#form-lightbox-1369701509296", 
                "padding" : 10,"margin" : 20,"opacity" : true,"modal" : false,"scrolling" : "","autoScale" : true,"autoDimensions" : true,"width" : 560,"height" : 340,"centerOnScroll" : false,"hideOnOverlayClick" : true,"hideOnContentClick" : false,"overlayShow" : true,"overlayOpacity" : 0.30,"overlayColor" : "#666","titleShow" : true,"titlePosition" : "outside","transitionIn, transitionOut" : "elastic","speedIn" : 300,"changeSpeed" : 300,"changeFade" : "fast","easingIn, easingOut" : "elastic","showCloseButton" : true,"enableEscapeButton" : true,
                "onClosed" : function(){ jQuery("#form-lightbox-1369701509296 iframe").attr("src", iFrame_1369701509296); } 
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery.fancybox(
                            jQuery("#form-lightbox-1369701509296").html(), {
                            "padding" : 10,"margin" : 20,"opacity" : true,"modal" : false,"scrolling" : "","autoScale" : true,"autoDimensions" : true,"width" : 560,"height" : 340,"centerOnScroll" : false,"hideOnOverlayClick" : true,"hideOnContentClick" : false,"overlayShow" : true,"overlayOpacity" : 0.30,"overlayColor" : "#666","titleShow" : true,"titlePosition" : "outside","transitionIn, transitionOut" : "elastic","speedIn" : 300,"changeSpeed" : 300,"changeFade" : "fast","easingIn, easingOut" : "elastic","showCloseButton" : true,"enableEscapeButton" : true,
                            "onClosed" : function(){ jQuery("#form-lightbox-1369701509296 iframe").attr("src", iFrame_1369701509296); } 
                        } 
                )
                },1000);
    });
    </script></p>
```

I cant find why i get this error because verify in the source code that:

because the script has been enqueed in the wp.

Anyone can help?

Regards

Comment: most likely a js error is triggered after adding the form-lightbox plugin so fancybox breaks afterwards

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 just in case

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i cant solve my problem already.