# enabling autocomplete ( jquery 1.9.1 ) breaks fancybox (1.3.4) on another element

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fancybox

I have a situation where I want to enable autocomplete on an input.  When I include jquery 1.9.1 fancybox breaks (needs 1.8.2).  I am looking over the documentation for upgrading fancybox but am having no luck.  The specific error message is $ is undefined.  this ought to just jump out at me, but I am not seeing the answer.  If you want to see the way I have it working without the autocomplete go here:  http://kewdos.co  Thanks

Comment: Can you post your codes? Why don't you use fancybox 2 ? Latest version is 2.1.4 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0 \[ f.browser is undefined / Cannot read property 'msie' \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of *deprecated* functions were removed/modified with jQuery 1.9/2.0 release, which may cause issues on plugins (like fancybox) which depend upon an earlier version of jquery.

You could use jquery-migrate plugin to help you with this transition. To do so, import jquery-migrate plugin right after jquery, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or use the *uncompressed* version, which logs the deprecated functions being used to the console:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```