# form Lightbox2 fancybox possible jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Hi I have taken over the work on a website http://test.makeusawebsite.com however no matter what type of lightbox I use I can not get these to display I believe this is a jquery conflict issue, but my jquery skills at present are basic and I feel after a couple of days on this that I am banging my head against a brick wall, I have tried to use contacts of my own but just don't get anywhere.

I get this error when checking the console with chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

For all I know I am making this worse instead of better or I could be just around the corner from the solution, but at present I feel like I am losing the plot, so if anyone out there could offer me some help it would be much appreciated, even if its just where to build up the skill in JQuery to understand this problem and resolve it myself.

Comment: this normally occurs when fancybox is not loaded. are you using the fancybox call before fancybox is implemented?

Comment: also, you are loading 2 times

Comment: will have a look Alex thanks, but I think it is being called before being used but will double check now

Comment: Alex looking at the source there is 2 versions of fancybox but one of these has been commented out, so I may just not be seeing the second load occurrance, can I check what you have found it in at present I am using google chrome and the inspect element option, also the script is being called within the header file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you are loading jQuery 2 times

Comment: yeah see what you mean thanks alex jQuery.js and JQuery.min.js

Comment: which would normally be the best version to keep

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your site, you are using FancyBox 1.3.4. This is not compatible with the version of jQuery you are using (1.9.1).

In order to resolve this, you need to update the version of FancyBox you are using to the latest version.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read#answer-14344290).

Comment: Hi the question you posted was one I had already viewed and I have made the suggested edits from that post to the fancybox script which have resolved the msie error but I am still unable to get fancybox to work and I have just removed one of the 2 jquery libraries which has currently disabled another part of the page but has made no difference to getting the fancybox to work.  Also I am using fancybox as part of the form lightbox 2 plugin

Comment: also now the error message I am getting which is only one of a few, related specifically to the fancybox is:      Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Comment: Having look at your site and I got error on your site is Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined. It's a typo mistake make jquery to "jQuery" in mauaw-portfolio-gallery.js line no 29

Comment: not in mauaw-portfolio-gallery.js  its in your current page. I think its in your theme's header.php file

Comment: thanks your a star will do that now

Comment: have had a look at that but had have removed that line as even when changing the jquery to jQuery it made no difference but I have also included it now in the muaw-portfolio-gallery.js file but still unable to get the main problem solved which is to get these lightboxes working

Comment: you are loading jQuery two times. Remove this script <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> from your header.php file.

Comment: removing the jquery scripts did not solve this however there were a couple of scripts running in the footer and moving these to the header and disabling the foundation.min.js allowed the lightbox to work, there was some other minor errors but this was the main conflict