# Soundcloud custom player bug

Tags: soundcloud

Soundcloud fails to acknowledge their bug with the custom players. Many sites are being affected. Here's a link to my previous question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993681/soundcloud-custom-player-skin-not-playing-next-tracks

Comment: What is the point of this post, really? Do you have an actual question about this problem, or are you looking for some kind of feedback from others on how to solve it, or what? As it stands, this is *not* a question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the bug exists as well.  I created an [issue](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/issues/60) about it on their github page, and i have also emailed support.  I've spent the last two days trying to see if i could solve it by modifying their code somehow, but i'm pretty sure the bug exists in the actual flash payload that is being delivered via their API, and not on the javascript end of things.

EDIT: ok, i came up with a temporary solution to circumvent soundcloud's bug.

In sc-player.js around line 209 you should see:

```
    load: function(track) {
      var url = track.uri;
      if(player){
       player.api_load(url);
      }else{
        // create a container for the flash engine (IE needs this to operate properly)
        $('<div class="sc-player-engine-container"></div>').appendTo(document.body).html(flashHtml(url));
      }
```

This is the call that injects the new track into the flash player using the api_load call.  Problem is that is totally not working right now. so instead of using that api, we just destroy the existing audio engine and replace it with a new one like so:

```
    load: function(track) {
      var url = track.uri;
      if(player){
       // player.api_load(url);
       $('.sc-player-engine-container').html(flashHtml(url));
      }else{
        // create a container for the flash engine (IE needs this to operate properly)
        $('<div class="sc-player-engine-container"></div>').appendTo(document.body).html(flashHtml(url));
      }
```

Now it will play tracks after the first track finishes, or when the user switches tracks.  This is not optimal because we have to keep loading an extra resource from soundcloud, but soundcloud has left us i a stick situation, and i see no other viable solution at the moment.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @apaul34208 I don't understand what you are trying to say.  I thought my answer was useful, at the time it was the only working solution to the problem.  I don't think i was being a help vampire, but perhaps i am not understanding what i did wrong.

Comment: Sorry, the person who asked the question asked it several times and appeared to show symptoms of being a help vampire. Just a heads up to not feed the vamps... It perpetuates the problem.

Comment: thanks for your solution @deweydb I'm wondering if after 6 months are  you still using this hack ? because is a bit slow :) or did you change to use soundmanager2? thx

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, i noticed that custom player doesn't work properly since few days.
I've found a solution for webkit browsers who support html5 audio only :
you have to include scripts as following (copied from sources):

1. widget js api: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js
2. soundcloud.player.api.js (grab from github soundclound custom player)
3. sc-player.js (grab from github soundclound custom player)

It should solve problems only on html5 audio supported browsers, but it still don't work with the flashplayer fallback. Firefox 21 Mac version doesn't support mp3 yet, and use flash for stream audio...

I'm waiting for an answer from soundcloud dev support about this point.

Cheers.

Comment: If you are still experiencing this issue, see my solution above, as a temporary fix.

Comment: thanks, the problem seems to have resolved "itself" for a few hours. Even the Flash audio engine, work again in my case, on browsers who are unable to stream audio via html5. Let me known if it's your case too.

Comment: Yes, soundcloud got back to me, and they said they have fixed it. I tested with their demo player and it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem in Safari and Chrome by following the Soundcloud Github page updates from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.9.0.  https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

I also had to replace `$.browser.msie` with `navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6]/i)` as described here:  [Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0 [ f.browser is undefined / Cannot read property 'msie' ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)

I contacted the Soundcloud developer who suggested it could be a Firefox/Flash issue.  Updating Flash did nothing for me, and the problem initially occurred simultaneously in all browsers.  I applied deweydb's workaround and everything works well.