# fancybox is not working with jquery version after 1.8.3

Tags: fancybox, jquery-1.9

i've been using fancybox with jquery 1.7 or 1.8 but it's not working at all with jquery 1.9 nor 1.10 nothing happens at all as it doesn't exist with these versions here's my js code

```
$(a"#ytvid").fancybox({
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 500,
    closeSpeed  : 500
});
```

and html code

```
<a href="#video" id="ytvid">play youtube video</a>
<div style="display:none;" id="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qbgBxr4H59A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0 \[ f.browser is undefined / Cannot read property 'msie' \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)

Answer (score 0):

Working after downloading new fancybox 2.1