# Fancybox Zoom Drag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using the Zoom helper of Fancybox https://github.com/Fab1en/fancyBox/blob/master/demo/index.html and now everything works except when I try to drag the item within the fancy box after zoom, I can't.
Can anyone help me please.
http://jsfiddle.net/2XhjG/1739/

```
    $(".fancybox")
.fancybox({
    arrows : false,

            helpers : {
                zoom : {
                    maxZoom: 5
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Possible discussion: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/pull/319

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution, it doesn't work for jQuery 9 or above. Try using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: because that forked version uses fancybox v2.0.6. Check this for further information http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987