# How can I play a locally stored video as lightbox effect in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, lightbox

I am wondering how can I play locally store videos on HTML5 with lightbox effects (where it pop-ups and play). I've tried a few options such as:

- http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#videos
- http://jbutz.github.io/bootstrap-lightbox/

But these are supporting youtube or Vimeo videos and doesn't seem to work with local videos.

I also looked at following question 
[Video in jQuery and Fancybox (Local video file mp4 Instead of Youtube)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134625/video-in-jquery-and-fancybox-local-video-file-mp4-instead-of-youtube) but the only thing I got to know is we need an external video player to play the video and it would not work on the mobile.

Is there any generic solution to this problem?

Comment: _`"But these are supporting youtube or Vimeo videos"`_ you mean they load an external html page (iframe)? Did you try putting your video in some html page and then use link of that page (instead of Youtube link)? Maybe show the code you tried for youtube so we can suggest a solution?

Comment: if the video is mp4/webm you should be able to play it using the `<video>` tag inside the pop-up, and not need an extra player...

Comment: Actually, fancybox v3 supports Youtube, Vimeo and HTML5 videos, see these demos - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#video

Comment: I think the OP is focussing on something different. Lightbox et al. work if the file is remote, however, if one uses a local file as an href, then it fails with an error "not allowed to load local resource". I have just encountered the same problem myself.