# Fancybox loading with javascript but not via class

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The coding works great if I change the href link to:

```
javascript:displaylightbox('http://google.com',{})
```

but then it doesn't work in firefox..So I'm doing it via class..which just doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/portal/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/portal/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/portal/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/portal/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://google.com" >google</a>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: see [Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)

Comment: no error in the console, also, in that post it says its updated to work with the 1.9.0 now

Comment: data-fancybox-type="iframe" - solved.

Comment: @kingkero : fancybox v2.1.3 or lower doesn't work with v1.9.0... fancybox v2.1.4+ does though (the OP seems to be using v2.1.5 so your recommendation doesn't apply)

Comment: @user2989499 : for the record: you can't open google inside an `iframe` ... you may open some external pages of your own though.