# Fancybox and jquery.min js conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, conflict

My Fancybox Works fine until i add Slippry Slider

I Suspect its because Library from Google conflict with the other, tried some ways but its not working

Code From Fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Code From Slippry

```
<script src="/source-code-pro-n4,n7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts-f0e4e0c2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-38942381-5', 'slippry.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you add your slider?

Comment: The Fancybox wont work

Comment: What does your console say...

Comment: you are loading two versions of jQuery when you may need only one. If loading the latest version of jQuery check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987