# jQuery upgrade makes poplight stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to update my website from jQuery 1.4.3 to 1.11.1 the last days and of course ran into several issues. Most of them I have fixed but I don't understand the latest error I get.

Before when I wanted to show a popup dialog I used this function

```
a.poplight[href=#?w=270]
```

But now it says

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a.poplight[href=#?w=270]**

Anyone else have had this issue when upgrading jQuery and what might be the issue?

Comment: Most likely poplight is using deprecated jQuery methods, try upgrading to jQuery v1.8.3 before

Comment: Should I upgrade to 1.8.3 first and the to 1.11.1? How would that help?

Comment: Update before to verify about deprecated elements

Comment: This is an example of a plugin having issues with deprecated methods after jQuery v1.9+ http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are using double '=' sign in expression, it must be quoted as string
try this

```
a.poplight[href*='#?w=270']
```

Comment: `try this` is not an answer. Answers should teach, not just give code

Comment: i'hv made change to post

Comment: @RUJordan Don't be so fast to judge a suggestion next time even though it was a TRY. This solved my problem!

Comment: @JoakimM it wasn't about the code quality (to be honest I didn't know if it was right or wrong). Just because the code is right, doesn't mean it's a good answer to future googlers. It's nothing personal, it's about good quality answers.

Comment: yes, RUJordan is right. initially i didn't explained my answer correctly