# jQuery Fancybox not working on site

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get fancy box to work on my site - I have followed the guide on the site but its still opening the image in a new tab.

You can see an example on adamhuxtable.com and if you click on the WhyEtihad image.

Comment: Depending on your fancybox version, you may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 2):

Your `jQuery` version is too old. I've encountered the same problem, and it is solved by using newer version of `jQuery`. I guess 1.8+ would work.

Comment: cheers thank you, figured that out 5mins after posting this. always the way lol