# JScrollPane and Fancybox conflict - Fancybox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jscrollpane

I'm setting up a gallery, with the pictures in a wide window in the middle of the page, controlled by a scrollbar. I've also set up a page with a form used to contact the artist to arrange a sale, and I want this page to open in a fancybox window.
The link to the form works, but it will not open in a fancybox window.

The scripts in the head of the page are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
$(function() {
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>

<script>    
$(function() {
$('.iframe').fancybox({
    width : '50%',
    height : '80%',
    titlePosition: 'outside'
}); // end fancybox
}); // end ready
</script>
```

The link meant for a fancy box window looks like this on the page:

```
<li><a href="form.html" class="iframe">buy</a></li>
```

My JS console says that it "Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" in the JQuery fancybox file, and also that `$('.iframe').fancybox({` is not a function, but it all seems to work fine in various tutorials and experiments I've pursued where JScrollPane is out of the picture.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 for more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using an old version of fancybox and new version of jquery.

Old version of fancybox depends on `jquery.browser` which is remove in all versions from jquery 1.9.

either use jquery migrate file or use the latest `fancybox`