# fancybox opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have following html:

```
<a href="createCompany/getOriginalImage/1" class="fancy_image"><img id="right_tab_image" src="createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/1" alt=""></a>
```

And following code executes(tested in debug) when page loads:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancy_image").fancybox({
            type        : 'image',
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
```

and to the the page include following sources:

[image]

But when I click on href image opens but in another tab.

What did I forget ?

Comment: Make sure is not a hoisting issue and jQuery is loading before any other js. Then check that fancybox.js loads before its js helpers as well. Then your custom code should be loaded at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An imitation of the supplied code seems to work:

### HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://picsofcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/11wwartsuewilkinslooktothecoast.jpg"
style='width:50px;'> 
<!-- Note that FancyBox ignores this width styling -->
<img src="http://picsofcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/11wwartsuewilkinslooktothecoast-150x150.jpg" alt="" /><br>
<b>Click to trigger Fancybox</b></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
       padding: 0,
       type        : 'image',
       openEffect  : 'none',
       closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvspghqb/).

So things you should try to get it working:

1. Use the latest version of jQuery and the latest version of fancybox. [Sometimes there are problems with the versions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read)
2. Make sure that `fancybox.js` is actually loaded
3. Specify your image links in the full `http://..` format

I think if you follow all these points, it'll work. Otherwise, check if any of the other plugins cause problems with fancybox.

Comment: **Make sure that fancybox.js is actually loaded** How to check it?

Comment: [**Multiple ways**](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=C43OVPPzLcaX-AaGyYGQAQ&gws_rd=cr#q=how+to+check+if+js+is+loaded). Easiest being to try a very simple example of fancybox and see if the behaviour is expected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes that worked. I dint have the type set to be image in fancybox. I ended up with the fancybox placing an empty placeholder div tag in place of the active flex slide. This caused the white space to appear in the background of the fancy box. it was fixed with the below settings.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery('.slides a.fancybox')
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
            arrows: true,
            type:'image'
        })
});
```

Comment: Not to forget that the anchor tag should have the href attribute with the path to the image you're targeting. I think thats the key.