# jQuery Fancybox - Close on ESC button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Guys i have an issue with jQuery Fancybox only in one particular page. When pressed ESC, the popup doesn't close. It happens only on one page. Rest of the pages where it has been used, works fine. It has been used like this everywhere

```
<a href="#newpopupcontainer" id="modalpopup" class="modalpopup">Link Name</a>

<div style="display:none;">
   <div id="newpopupcontainer" class="newpopupcontainer">
      Content                           
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.modalpopup").fancybox({
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none'            
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
```

Coming to the jQuery version, 1.11.0 is being used. This happens only in one particular page. In all the other pages, popup closes when pressed ESC. Any idea what could be the possible cause?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 0):

Older Fancybox versions are not compatible with the newest versions of jquery. A solution is to upgrade to Fancybox 2.1.5, and update a small piece of code:

Change `$("a.modalpopup").fancybox({` to `$("#modalpopup").fancybox({`.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vojyzcdb/

**Edit 1:**

To include the newest version of Fancybox, you will need `jquery.fancybox.min.css` and `jquery.fancybox.pack.js`. Those two files can be included like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

The code in your editted start post should work fine after this change.

Comment: I forgot to add class to <a> tag. Now edited my question.

Comment: When you say update, those two files (js and CSS) needs to be updated right?

Comment: @SagarRaj check the edit, it should work fine afterwards.

Comment: Nope. The pop itself doesn't appear when i include this 2.1.5

Comment: Weird, it works for me. I'm sorry, but I don't think I have the skills to help you further.

Comment: Yes. Only on one page it has a problem. Rest of the pages work fine. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could try copying the contents from the working page to the faulty page (back it up first!), and then check if you use the same Javascript and include the exact same files.