# How to rewrite .removeAttribute to make it compatible with jquery 3.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, backwards-compatibility

The following excerpt from a [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) script does not work under jquery 3.3.1.  It works with jquery 1.11.0.

How would you rewrite this statement without ***removeAttribute***, which is reported as not being a function?

```
a.support.opacity || 
(p.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter"), 
f.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter"));
```

Comment: Are you looking for [removeProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty) instead?

Comment: I don't know whether removeProperty or removeAttr would be proper. 
 But per answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344289/fancybox-doesnt-work-with-jquery-v1-9-0-f-browser-is-undefined-cannot-read (towards the bottom of the page) the attribute has to be replaced.  I just don't understand how he handled the syntax.

Comment: Assuming `a` is a jQuery object then the issue is the use of [`support`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/). The documentation suggests using Modernizr for feature detection instead.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to the latest version of fancybox?

Comment: @Janis It's a script based on fancybox written by a third-party developer.  Can't upgrade without rewriting the script.

Comment: Why do you think `removeAttribute` is deprecated in jquery?  It's not a jquery method by the fact you've used `.get(0).style` (<- DOM element, not a jquery object) (and the fact is just a verbose name) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Comment: You're correct, I was thinking of .unbind, which also needed to be replaced.  Corrected the original question.  In any case, replacing removeAttribute with removeProperty solved the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all instances of ***removeAttribute*** with ***removeProperty*** and ***.unbind*** with ***.off*** solved the issue entirely.

The old script now loads with jquery 3.3.1.